# Combine Columns Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have problem combining two pandas dataframe columns.

I have tried

```
df.apply(lambda row: datetime.datetime(row['Date'], row['Time']), axis=1)
```

but gives me error:

```
TypeError: ('integer argument expected, got float', u'occurred at index 0')
```

My Data looks like this:

```
     Date  Time     Open     High      Low    Close     Volume  
0  19980102   959  73.3678  73.3678  73.3678  73.3678   6619.390   
1  19980102  1000  73.3678  73.3678  73.3377  73.3377    794.326   
2  19980102  1001  73.2848  73.2848  73.2697  73.2697    264.775   
3  19980102  1002  73.2697  73.2697  73.2697  73.2697   7943.260   
4  19980102  1003  73.2697  73.2697  73.2697  73.2697  19858.200
```

Note that I've converted everything to float when reading in the data. I am reading in line by line using linecache.getline which returns an entire string of each line. I then use `.split(',')` to fix this. But afterwards can't convert to datetime. Do i need to convert the dates in to integers?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're reading the lines in like that? with `read_csv()` you can pass `parse_dates=[['Date', 'Time']]` and the two columns will be combined into a single Datetime column. You may need to write a custom `date_parser` function.

Comment: I've got a massive csv file but I don't need all the lines...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```
In [41]
df['datetime']=map(datetime.datetime, 
    df['Date']/10000, 
    (df['Date']-df['Date']/10000*10000)/100,
    df['Date']%100, df['Time']/100, df['Time']%100,)

In [42]:
print df

       Date  Time     Open     High      Low    Close     Volume  \
0  19980102   959  73.3678  73.3678  73.3678  73.3678   6619.390   
1  19980102  1000  73.3678  73.3678  73.3377  73.3377    794.326   
2  19980102  1001  73.2848  73.2848  73.2697  73.2697    264.775   
3  19980102  1002  73.2697  73.2697  73.2697  73.2697   7943.260   
4  19980102  1003  73.2697  73.2697  73.2697  73.2697  19858.200   

             datetime  
0 1998-01-02 09:59:00  
1 1998-01-02 10:00:00  
2 1998-01-02 10:01:00  
3 1998-01-02 10:02:00  
4 1998-01-02 10:03:00
```

If your `'Date'` and `'Time'` are both `float64`, you need these two lines first:

```
df['Date']=df['Date'].astype('int64')
df['Time']=df['Time'].astype('int64')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'a' : [1,2,3],
    'b' : [2,3,4]
})
test['combine'] = test[['a','b']].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x.values]), axis=1)
```